# Recursively rename files using wdired

Tags: dired

I have many files in many directories all with the same filename pattern. I want to rename them by replacing a substring with another, e.g. `bla_A.mat` to `bla_B.mat`.

I know I can do this quite easily in a directory using `wdired` mode and `replace-string`. How can I do that same operation recursively on all my directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to do this with `dired`:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-name-dired` <kbd>RET</kbd> select the top-level directory where all such files exist, <kbd>RET</kbd> `bla-*.mat`.
2. <kbd>t</kbd> will mark all files in the buffer.
3. <kbd>%R</kbd> `\(.*\)_A\.mat` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\1_B.mat` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

More on renaming files: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transforming-File-Names.html#Transforming-File-Names

Comment: Worked great thanks - I actually used `wdired` after step 1 so I check I hadn't screwed up first.

Comment: `C-u s R RET` in the dired buffer lists all files recursively also.